# asp.net mvc TextAreaFor is not getting validated as a required field

Tags: jquery-mobile, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I have a data entry field where I'm gathering notes.  The note data element is required for each note.  Here's my model:

```
public interface INoteDataEntryViewModel : IMobilePageDataContract
{
    int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Note is required")]
    String Note { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(@"Note Date")]
    DateTime NoteDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that I have the Required attribute for the Note property.

I'm using Razor to display the data entry form element:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Note)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Note)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Note)
</div>
```

When I use "@Html.TextAreaFor" then there is no validation for the required field and i can submit the form.  However, if I change to "@Html.TextBoxFor", then validation happens for the required field and I cannot submit the form.  Any ideas on why validation fails for TextAreaFor?  I'm using unobtrusive ajax and am jQueryMobile.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

The client-side validation does not work for the Html.TextAreaFor() helper, here is the [related issue reported on Codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576).

To make it work, you have to decorate the 'Note' property with the `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` attribute. And in the view, use `Html.EditorFor()` helper instead of the `Html.TextAreaFor()` helper mehthod.

Updated Model:

```
public interface INoteDataEntryViewModel : IMobilePageDataContract
{
    int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Note is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    String Note { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(@"Note Date")]       
    DateTime NoteDate { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Note)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Note)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Note)
</div>
```