# Data Annotation doesn't not work if control generates from List View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have below view model

```
public class QuestionarrieAnswersViewModel
{
    public long QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="required")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 255 characters are allowed.")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

and i am generating view in below way

```
@model List<BusinessLayer.Models.ViewModel.QuestionarrieAnswersViewModel>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveQuestionarrie", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "OnBegin", OnComplete = "OnComplete" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{   
    for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
    {
     <div class="control-group">
        <div class="head_form">
            <label class="control-label">@Model[i].Question</label>
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m[i].Answer)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Answer)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m[i].QuestionID)         
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }           
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>                     
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have set dataannotation on Answer field in above model but its not applying in above view while it works if i generate view in below way

```
@model BusinessLayer.Models.ViewModel.QuestionarrieAnswersViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveQuestionarrie", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "OnBegin", OnComplete = "OnComplete" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{   
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Answer)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.QuestionID)
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>                     
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What's going wrong here...

Comment: Are you actually calling `ModelState.IsValid`?

Comment: validations are not even working on client side.

Comment: Out of interest, changing your `button` submit to an `input type="submit"` does that make any difference?

Comment: :) no, its not even generating validation for the fields, i can't see them if i check the html source from browser.

Comment: @mattytommo: Do you have any idea why its not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc TextAreaFor is not getting validated as a required field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045964/asp-net-mvc-textareafor-is-not-getting-validated-as-a-required-field)

Comment: @nemesv: No, read my question again, it works with textarea if i generate the view from model (not list model)

Comment: @nemesv: Even if i change it to TextBoxFor from TestAreaFor, it doesn't wok.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Change it to `EditorFor`

Comment: @mattytommo: let me check...

Comment: @mattytommo: yeah, it works don't know how but it works....thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi No problems, added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fire those validation rules, you'll need to use an `EditorFor` instead of a `TextAreaFor`.

It's because there's an outstanding issue with validation of `TextArea`'s, see here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576.

Comment: Can you also please let me know how it worked with editor while it was not working with TextBoxFor or TextAreaFor with List View Model?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Added a link, it's basically an outstanding issue in MVC validation

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in the version of jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js that was released with ASP.NET MVC3.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156367/678338) is on the same bug, the solution to this is to upgrade to the latest version of jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js - either grab it from an MVC4 project or update using NuGet.

The jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js script doesn't seem to have a version number so if you search in the script for a function called **escapeAttributeValue**, then this is a version of the script that has this bug fix.

The problem that is addressed in the bug fix is how to handle markup generated having name attributes containing characters that need escaping in a jQuery selector.  In this case

```
<textarea cols="20" name="[0].Answer" rows="2"></textarea>
```

needs this selector

```
$('[name=\\[0\\]\\.Answer]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The client-side DataAnnotation (validation) does not work for the Html.TextAreaFor() helper.

To make it work, you have to decorate the 'Answer' property with the [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] attribute. And in the view, use Html.EditorFor() helper instead of the Html.TextAreaFor() helper mehthod.

See similar SO answer [asp.net mvc TextAreaFor is not getting validated as a required field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216280/819071).

Comment: Its works perfectly without any decoration. I have mentioned the same in my question also.

Comment: Even if i change it to TextBoxFor from TestAreaFor, it doesn't wok.

Comment: I have mentioned to use Html.EditorFor() instead of Html.TextAreaFor()